# SharePoint Access Services App Not working (greyed out)

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, uls, access-services

I am trying to setup Access Services on SharePoint 2016. Server is hosted on Azure Platform.

When I look at the ULS logs. What am I looking for?

How would I know there is something that is irregular with my setup or an error throwing that I could resolve? I have filter all "Access Services".

[image: ULS Log SharePoint]

Maybe this is an error that will cause:
Any ideas to resolve?

> ApplicationDatabase.AlterDatabaseProperties: ServerName='KRITHSHAREPOINT'; DatabaseName='db_bbcf9886_b86a_4b98_b09c_7c7352675d1c'; DatabaseType='Access'. Failed with exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The sp_configure value 'contained database authentication' must be set to 1 in order to alter a contained database.  You may need to use RECONFIGURE to set the value_in_use.  ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
>    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource 1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Data.SqlSession.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand command, SqlInfoMessageEventHandler handler)
>   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Data.SqlSession.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand command)
>   at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.Database.RetryableSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>    at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.Database.SqlClientExtensions.ExecuteNonQueryLogged(SecureSqlCommand command, SqlCommandScope scope)
>    at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.Database.SqlScriptBatcher.ExecuteBatch(SecureSqlCommand command, SqlString batch, SqlCommandScope scope, Boolean logBatch)
>    at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.Database.SqlScriptBatcher.ExecuteDynamicScript(SqlString script, SqlTransaction transaction, Boolean logScript)
>    at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.Database.AccessDatabase.AlterDatabasePropertiesInternal()
>    at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.Database.ApplicationDatabase.ExecuteOperation(Action operation, String operationType)  ClientConnectionId:6be5a95c-25fd-488f-a94f-492d241f8faf  Error Number:12824,State:1,Class:16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run this on your SQL Server.

```
sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1;
GO 
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Note that Access Services has been retired from SharePoint Online. You may want to give alternatives a thought before perusing this technology on-premises, as well.

Comment: Thank you Trevor, the app no longer greyed out. But does not work on this link: http://apps-8d1fc57f2d6b38.kjhsd.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/sites/kjhsd/AccessSite/AccessService/default.aspx. COuld there something be wrong with my DNS settingS?

Comment: This is the error I get now :  ServerSession.ExecuteWebMethodCore: RetryCount: 0, Session=. ProvisionDatabase failed on Proxy Server: Url='http://SHAREPOINT:32843/b897319197d24b649450a7c943e2b297/AccessService.svc', HS=0, AdjustedHS=0, ServerStateFlags=None, LastReceivedResponse (seconds ago)=0, Unreachable=False, RunningLocally=True. CommunicationException: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.DatabaseProviderMessage]: The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason. (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.DatabaseProviderMessage).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the issue is related to the [MinRole Server Roles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346114%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), 
Where the `Access Service` is **only** available at the below **Minroles**:

1. Front-end
2. Single-server farm
3. Front-end with Distributed Cache.

[image]

The `Access Service` is **not** available at the below **Minroles**.

1. Application
2. Distributed cache.
3. Search
4. Custom
5. Application with Search

For more details check [MinRole and associated services in SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt667910(v=office.16).aspx)

---

**So** you will not be able to configure access service! , if the server Minrole is not one of the following

1. Front-end
2. Single-server farm
3. Front-end with Distributed Cache.

**Fortunately,** you can to convert your server roles in a SharePoint farm deployment as mentioned at [Role conversion using MinRole in SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790700(v=office.16).aspx)

Comment: Thanks M.Qassas, Min Role is complaint running a Single Server Farm setup.

Comment: How do I do role conversion in Single Server Farm? Do I add more servers?
 The video shows for Multiple Server Roles. Much Appreciated

Comment: no need to do a role conversion you already have Single Server Farm role that includes Access service, Try to check the provided answer from Trevor Seward and if  his solution solve your issue, please don't forget to accept and upvote **his** answer, Thanks